# Converting double values into time in QGIS's Field calculator

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, time, double

How can I achieve the following result (in column "output", *string*) in QGIS attribute table?

[image]

The values in "duration" were calculated with some other formulas and represent a certain time duration given in double data type.
So 2.584 actually means 2 hours and 0.584 hours (=35 minutes).

Is there a way/expression to get the "output" column directly from the "duration" column in QGIS Field Calculator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
concat(to_string(floor(duration)),':',to_string(round((duration*60) % 60, 0)))
```

Comment: Please ask it as a new question. Do not forget to include an error that you got.